# Автоматическое проставление тега

Tags: предложение, метки

На ruSO Есть метки [python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python), [python-2.x](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-2.x) и [python-3.x](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-3.x).
Версии python 2.x и 3.х частично несовместимы.
Насколько я понимаю, метки [python-2.x](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-2.x) и [python-3.x](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-3.x) должны ставиться в том случае, если вопрос специфичен относительно версии языка. При этом люди часто ставят эту метку указывая их версию совсем забывая про главную метку [python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python).

Вопрос: возможно имеет смысл проставлять метку [python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) автоматически?

Answer (score 1):

Данное предложение ещё и с давних пор появлялось в том или ином виде на метах разных сайтов сети Stack Exchange и звучит оно следующим образом: нужно создать иерархию меток/тегов. В наиболее общем виде оно [живёт на главной мете](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/58073/346987) и на момент публикации ответа оно отклонено по причине сложности создания и поддержания данной иерархии, которая на самом деле рождает кучу сопутствующих проблем.

В любом случае данный вопрос обсуждать здесь не сильно и полезно ввиду того, что данный функционал требует создание нового механизма иерархий, а функциональность сайтов сети StackExchange должна быть почти одинаковой (отличия обычно в очень небольших, почти косметических пределах), а значит такой глобальный вопрос должен быть всерьёз (чтобы внедрили, а не только для обратной связи и поддержки) рассмотрен на главной мете. Поскольку данный вопрос уже рассмотрен и по нему вынесен отрицательный вердикт, то остаются варианты либо смириться, либо написать пост или добавить в [существующий](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/58073/346987) как именно можно будет построить иерархию, решив или не создав сопуствующие проблемы.